# Numba does not speed up my code

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am trying to speed up a part of my code using Numba. But, it does not work properly. Actually, I don't see any improvement! Can anybody give me some advice how to fix it?

By the way, all the input variables are 1D/2D/3D numpy variables

```
import numba as nb
@nb.jit 
def Permutation(Spect, Blob_Len, Fs, alpha, Terminate,
                    x, y, z, Per_IndexH1, Per_IndexH2, P_Value, MeanSpect, TempPVal, Boundary): 

  for i in range(Terminate):

      TempPVal[:] = 0.0
      DS1 = Spect[:, :, Per_IndexH1[i, 0 : Boundary]]
      DS2 = Spect[:, :, Per_IndexH2[i, Boundary:]]
      MS1 = np.sum(DS1, axis = 2)
      MS2 = np.sum(DS2, axis = 2)

      TempPVal[np.abs(MS1 - MS2) > MeanSpect] = 1
      P_Value = P_Value + TempPVal


  P_Value = P_Value / Terminate 
  return P_Value
```

Comment: Did you try using `NumPy` ufuncs instead to vectorize things if the focus is perfomance.

Comment: Please provide the input types and sizes of all arrays so that it is possible to run the function. Also, what version of Numba are you using and how did you time the function?

Comment: @Alen indeed NumBa will only affect the for loop, since all the other operations are already vectorized. I would expect av improvement only if this for loop was a big one

Comment: Josh, I am using Spyder(Python 3.5) on Windows 7, 64 bits.

Comment: I use time.time() to measure the runtime. By the way, the type of all input arguments is np.array. Spect: (41,9600,40),  Per_IndexH1 : (5000, 20), Per_IndexH2 : (5000, 20), P_Value : (41,9600),  MeanSpect: (41,9600), TempPVal : (41,9600). Other parameters are scalars: Boundary = 20, Blob_Len=0.05, Fs = 4800, alpha = 0.05, Terminate = 5000, x = 41, y = 9600, z = 40.  Thanks

Comment: In some cases you can increase the performance by specifying the types of arguments, for example like @jit(float32(float32, float32)) (http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.27.0/user/jit.html)

Comment: And one more thing I can suggest on the base of my small experience: try to start your code in nopython mode, for example @jit(float32(float32, float32), nopython=True). In most cases if you can do it you will have reasonable speedup, and if you can't the speedup is small or even negative.